# Is this correct usage of concat?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, concatenation

```
$this->db->query("SELECT *
FROM posts
LEFT JOIN sub_category on     
sub_category.sub_id = posts.category_post_id
LEFT JOIN categories ON categories.cat_id = sub_category.parent_id
LEFT JOIN images ON images.img_post_id = post.ID WHERE sub_category.sub_id=". $sub_id. " AND
posts.title LIKE %".$keyword."% concat(price,' ', curency) as price,curency,
case when curency= 'EUR' then concat(price,' ',curency) 
     when curency= 'USD' then concat(price,' ',curency) * 0.73
end as in_euros
ORDER BY CAST(in_euros as DECIMAL) ".$start_from." LIMIT".$num.",".$start)->result_array();

return $query;
```

Can anyone explain me how to use concat in a case like this one here.

Thanks.

Comment: CONCAT and GROUP_CONCAT are both virtually useless

Comment: Your problem isn't just with concat, here... this query has several syntax errors (as well as security vulnerabilities).

Comment: If I were you I would: 1. Use Active Record instead of building query manually 2. Connect currencies and prices using php instead of case() function in MySql (for flexibility).

Comment: Yeah i got it working in active record like $this->db->select('CONCAT'.....);

Comment: concat(price * 0.73,' ',curency) would work fine I guess. concat merge fields so you cannot give 2 aliases for concatenated field